# How to get ModuleBaseName using GetForegroundWindow function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I can get handle from GetForegroundWindow function. And I want to get BaseName
of handle. So i used GetModelBaseName function. But I guess this function was not work correctly.

```
TCHAR TitleName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
HANDLE hFirst = GetForegroundWindow();
GetModuleBaseName(hFirst, NULL, TitleName, MAX_PATH);
_tprintf(TEXT("%s \n"), TitleName);
```

Tell me, what is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the path of your current process? If yes then you are doing it wrong

Comment: GetModuleBaseName() requires a process handle.  Use GetWindowProcessThreadId() to map the window handle to a process ID.  Then OpenProcess() to get the process handle.  You must have sufficient rights to snoop around like that, elevation might be required.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, I'm trying to retrieve the path of current process. And I tried that method you said. But I guess that GetCurrentProcess function can't get other application in console system. ex. Running main function, I executed other application like chrome. In this situation, GetCurrentProcess can't get chrome. Have you any Idea to solve this problem? teach me please.

Comment: @Asesh: `GetCurrentProcess` doesn't return a *window* handle! It returns a *process* handle (actually, a pseudo-handle); don't mistake one for the other, they are completely different beasts - you may have a window handle (`HWND`) with the same value as a "kernel" handle (`HANDLE`), but they would refer to completely different objects.

Comment: @MatteoItalia sorry, that was a typo. Couldn't edit it so I have removed it

Comment: Thank you guys, I find GetWindowModuleFileName function. It may help to solve my problem.

Comment: That function @HansPassant mentioned is correctly spelled [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) ;-)

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong, that's why it's returning false and GetLastError will return ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (6).

```
HWND WINAPI GetForegroundWindow(void);
```

Will return the current foreground window and will return it's window handle of type HWND.

You can do this to retrieve the filename of your application:

```
TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(NULL), szName, MAX_PATH);
```

Besides, you can also use GetModuleFileName or GetMappedFileName to retrieve the full path of your application

**Edit:** He wants to do something else too. To retrieve the path of another process, you will have to open that process with a process id. For instance, if 9912 is the process id of Chrome then you can execute the following code to retrieve it's path

```
HANDLE process = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 9912);
if (process)
{
    char file_path[MAX_PATH];
    if (::GetModuleFileNameEx(process, nullptr, file_path, MAX_PATH))
    {
        std::cout << file_path << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error retrieving path" << std::endl;
    }

    ::CloseHandle(process);
}
```

Comment: Consider using `GetProcessImageFileName()` or `QueryFullProcessImageName()` instead, then you can open the process using `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` instead of `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`